# Syntactic Sugar for passing React props with the same key and value into component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I find myself often writing components that look like this

```
<Component propOne={propOne} propTwo={propTwo} propThree={propThree} />
```

Is there something that exists that works something along these lines (obviously this doesn't work):

```
<Component { propOne, propTwo, propThree } />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<Component { ...props} />

where props = { propOne, propTwo, propThree } object of props.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Component {...{propOne, propTwo, propThree}} />
```